# Blurred or blank google map when animating camera

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm developing android app and I'm tracking user movement. I want to animate the camera when user moves (on every onLocationChange call). Firstly I was doing it like that and it was working fine:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location
                .getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
```

Here is a screenshot of the screen when using this snippet: [image]

But as you can see it's not an animation, so I wrote this:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .zoom(zoom)
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                        .getLongitude())).build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

But it's not working fine, map is moving with animation but streets are blurred and streets' names are not visible (look at the screenshot):

[image]

I was also trying animation without zoom - same result. Map gets clear only after when I press zoom buttons however some points and routes are still blurred. So any ideas how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same problem.. If I move the map with my finger it immediately gets clear. Did you find a solution? Thanks

Comment: this might be due to the slow data connection . is your data connection is fast enough.

Comment: @FidelEduardoLópez I am also having same problem, did you guys found any solution?

Comment: @Meet I don't remember well, but try using animateCamera with a new created camera position.

Comment: @FidelEduardoLópez I am using that method, but the map is getting vlurry when continuously this method is called programmatically. (i.e take 3 camera positions very far from each other, and when you animate to those positions at some delay, between that do not touch the screen, then map is getting blurred).

Comment: Map require 1 sec to update the map tiles if your animation continues upto 1 sec you map will not get clear. You have to take pause between two animate calls